# how to start listening on port 22

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I am new to Linux system.
I am having trouble configuring ssh.

```
:~$ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

When I tried to debug it. I got this.

```
:~$ ssh -vvv localhost
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Some other commands that i ran and got no success.

```
:~$ sudo iptables INPUT -p udp -dport 22
Bad argument `INPUT'.
Try 'iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

I got no output on running `sudo netstat -anp | grep sshd` I guess because machine is not listing to port 22. I don't know how to fix that?

```
:~$ sudo ufw verbose
[sudo] password for hduser1: 
Status: inactive.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have installed openssh-server

```
apt-get install openssh-server
```

and make sure it is running

```
service ssh restart
```

See status of openssh-server:

```
systemctl status ssh
```

If there are any errors, try to fix them and restart ssh server.

Comment: Unit ssh.service could not be found. in my case