# OPEN SSH not listening on Port 22

Tags: 20.04, openssh, sftp

I installed Ubuntu 20.4 (and included Open SSH) as virtual machine on Virtual Box on a Windows 10 laptop. I installed Samba to allow for machine name connection.

Below shows the listeners on Port 22, and the status of SSH.

[image]

The lines in my `ssh_config` file that are not commented out are:

```
Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf 
Host * 
   Port 22 

Match Group filetransfer 
   ChrootDirectory %h 
   X11Forwarding no 
   AllowTcpForwarding no 
   ForceCommand internal-sftp 
   PasswordAuthentication yes
   PubkeyAuthentication no
```

I was going to try a user/password authentication first, then after I got that working was going to do a public key authentication.

[image]

From Windows command prompt, I can ping the machine, but I cannot do a "telnet" to port 22.

I also ran this command to disable any firewall:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

From this related post ([how to start listening on port 22](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856771/how-to-start-listening-on-port-22)), I tried the following from the Ubuntu terminal:

```
ssh -vvv localhost
```

I'm not sure what that does, as I want to connect from my Windows machine. 
It responds with the following:

```
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_confg line 19: cinclude /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files 
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config lin 21: Applying optiosn for * 
debug2: checking match for "group filetransfer' but localhost original localhost 
Unsupported Match attribute Group 
/etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Bad Match condition
```

I'm not sure if I should have run that, but maybe it's indicating my `ssh_config` is not correct?  I checked it with several blogs.

I followed the tutorial here to set up the user and group: https://gist.github.com/lymanlai/3008244

When I installed Ubuntu 20.4, I checked the box that said to "Install OpenSSH Server" as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Look in the link you posted, `Match group filetransfer`, but in you config is `Match Group filetransfer ` with a capital G, following the error `Unsupported Match attribute Group`.

Comment: i tried both with cap and not capital in attempt to fix.

Comment: Most examples have capital G.  This link https://serverfault.com/questions/419684/sftp-ssh-failing-after-adding-match-group-clause had similar issue, and links to https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes, so I will try that looking at those suggestions.

Comment: Is it even valid to type "ssh localhost" from the Ubuntu machine?  What is that trying to accomplish?  If the config file is bad, wouldn't open ssh fail to start?

Comment: There's a difference between `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`; if the former is bad, then yes the ssh *service* may fail to start, whereas if the latter is bad, the service will start but clients started *from the same machine* (such as when you execute `ssh localhost`) may fail.

Comment: There must be a config error. Look at the `systemctl status ssh` command: the status is `active (exited)`, and it should be `active (running)`. Look at the last lines of `sudo journalctl -u ssh`.

Comment: FWIW `lsof -i:22` run with regular user privileges may fail to show anything even if the service is listening. Try `sudo lsof -i:22` or `sudo netstat -nlpt | grep :22`

Comment: Okay, it sounds like I should have been sshd_config all along.  I changed it now, and restarted sshd.  sshd is running, but over all result is the same, I still cannot TELNET to port 22 from windows.

Comment: sudo lsof -i:22 stlil shows no listeners on port 22, even though sshd is running.  netstat says not found. I installed net-tools, but even sudo netstats -nlpt just hsows about 8 lins, an no port 22.  I see smdb (samba?) on 139 and 1:631 and tcp6 on 445 and tcp on 139

Comment: "TELNET" to port 22?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - What are you asking?  Telnet is a command to test if an IP address and port is open and something listening.  I'm trying to connect from my desktop Windows to my virtual box Ubuntu, when that is done, I will try WinSCP to do an SFTP file transfer.  The IP address Pings okay.

Comment: To me TELNET is a command to connect to an old, unsecured kind of server that listened on port 23. But maybe it's used for other things.

Comment: @OrganicMarble To me TELNET is the lowest level of command that proves if there is connectivity, or if a firewall is blocking, or if a service is not running/listening.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I changed sshd_config to match what I posted in the question.

Comment: OK. Mine has a lot more stuff uncommented than that.

Comment: @Jos - missed your comment earlier today.  Looked at the journa file but didn't see anything major.   I just did "sudo apt install openssh-server" and now it works.  I don't understand unless either 1) it wasn't installed, or 2) it upgraded to a newer version.  The install said "The following NEW packages will be installed:" ncurses-term openssh-sftp-server ssh-import-id.  So is the SFTP piece not included with Open SSH that comes with the original install?  I'm recording a tutorial video on how to use Open SSH on Windows (done), and now Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

and now it's working.  If anyone can give a better explanation, I will vote their answer. 
I thought that OpenSSH was already installed, and it included SFTP server, but maybe not. I had the sshd_config file on my disk.

I did a whole new install and it worked from the start.  The differences were:

1) I didn't install any machine name resolution so Windows could connect by machine name (I will try that later)

2) I didn't install any desktop, using the command line only this time.

Other notes: If using Virtual Box for the Virtual Machine, changing network adapter to bridge adapter so you get a 192... address instead of a 10... address.