# Isn't a status of active (exited) an oxymoron?

Tags: services, 20.04, openssh

How is one supposed to interpret a status of "active (exited)" on a service such as SSH or SSHD? (This is the results of the command:

```
sudo systemctl status sshd
```

How can it be active if it exited? If it exited, wouldn't it be inactive? It seems like active is one status and exited is another status.  So why both listed, and why one in parentheses?

Relates back to this question I posted earlier today; but I didn't want to muddy it up with this question. 
[OPEN SSH not listening on Port 22](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234879/open-ssh-not-listening-on-port-22)

Comment: And what about `systemctl status ssh.socket`?

Comment: @jpalecek I ran that and it says "Active: inactive (dead)", but I'm not sure how that answers the question I asked here.  I did finally get the connection open and SSHD running, but I'm asking how to interpret what "active (exited)" means.